# How can I run a python script through a webserver and return results to javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, python, gearman

I want to take results from a web page, sent from dom as json through ajax, then send this data to a python script, run it, then return the new results back as json. I was told a php script running gearman would be a good bet, but I'm still not sure how that would work.

Comment: you can use PHP to call system scripts and programs, and it *should* capture anything echo'd back to it from those scripts. `$return=system(/path/to/script.py);` as long as the script is executable by your webserver.

Comment: Make a python cgi and read the post/get parameters.

Comment: Why would going through a PHP script even seem like a good idea? Just run the python script on the server.

Comment: Agreed with @Wooble: the PHP script adds unnecessary complexity to the application.  Have Python parse the JSON data, process it, and return the results as JSON.  Then you simply need to get your web server to run Python.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example using `twisted` and `jquery`.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import json
import time

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource


class DataPage(Resource):
        isLeaf = True

        def render_GET(self, request):

                htmlFile = open("template.html")
                html = open("template.html").read()
                htmlFile.close()

                return html

        def render_POST(self, request):
                print request.args
                data = request.args['data'][0]
                print data
                return json.dumps(data[::-1])

resource = DataPage()
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(38123, factory)
reactor.run()
```

and the html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function flipData(){

            $.post("http://localhost:38123/", { data: "makeitbackwards" },
            function(data){
                    alert(data);
            }, "json");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="flipData()">Get Time</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your Python script in your CGI directory and use the `cgi` and `json` modules in your script to read AJAX from post/get params. Of course you *can* do a system call from PHP to run a Python script, but I can't think of a good reason why you would.